# Multiple IP Settings to Emulate Multiple Devices

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, ip, network-adapter

Here is the Setup

An Ethernet IPv4/UDP network based control system, with 20 different devices attached.
A test facility for testing 2 of these devices.
Simulator Software to simulate any of the other devices.
Two Windows-7 based laptop PCs to run the simulator software.

Each software simulator, when it initializes, it is supposed to set the IP of the PC to the IP of the device it is simulating. This used to work, but after a Windows security update a while back, the program is blocked from doing this even when opened with Admin privileges. Additionally, the simulator software will only work with the FIRST IP addressing setting of the FIRST physical adapter, so using multiple adapters or even multiple settings on one adapter will not work. I have since been forced to manually change the IP settings every time I change simulated devices. Also, I can only simulate up to two of these other devices at a time and I have had a need to simulate more.

I need a solution short of recoding someone else's software (I have access to the code, but not the original programmer, so this could take months). I've contemplated using VirtualBox, and putting each simulator software in it's own Virtual machine on the laptop. I have thought of three ways I might be able to do this, but not sure which ones may work.

1. Connect multiple USB to Ethernet dongles to the laptop, one for each device. Set each adapter to a specific address for a piece of simulated hardware and tie each Virtual Machine to a specific adapter, which I know how to do in VirtualBox. That way, in each virtual box, the adapter that's tied in looks like the FIRST setting of the FIRST adapter to the program, even if it is not so on the actual machine. The question is - is there a limit to how many different Ethernet adapters I can have on Windows 7? I'm thinking if I put a big usb hub and 18 dongles I'm bound to run into issues.
2. Use a smaller number of Ethernet dongles (1 or 2), and set multiple settings on each one using netsh. Is there a way to Tie each VirtualBox to a specific set of settings rather than just the physical adapter? I do not know how to do that if so.
3. Use a smaller number of Ethernet dongles (1 or 2), do not change any settings in Windows 7, but use different IP settings on the virtual controller within each VirtualBox. Will this work? Will the IP set in VirtualBox be used when it hits the real network?

I would prefer to do #2. If it's possible, how can I do it? If not, what is my best path for success?

Comment: "This used to work, but after a Windows security update a while back, the program is blocked from doing this" uninstall the update would appear to be the easiest solution.

Comment: The PC is required to have the latest security updates or it is not allowed to connect to any real parts of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Number 3 worked. Use "bridged adapter" in the "Network" settings of the virtual machine and bridge to the actual physical network adapter being used.
Doing this, traffic came in to the network port for all IPs and the VirtualBox Host Bridge "Adapter" routes the packets to the appropriate VM. Only one physical port was required. I've been able to run multiple VMs all with their own virtual port tied in.